# How to properly combined columns into one column using R

Tags: r

I have 3 sets of data. Each one is a column of variables:

```
A      B     C
81     35    31
62     34    33
46     36    31
45     31    33
81     35    31
62     34    33
46     36    31
45     31    33
81     35    31
62     34    33
46     36    31
45     31    33
```

I have been trying to use rbind to combine these three data sets into one dataset with one column.

```
Combine<-rbind(A,B,C)
```

Instead I get something this, where not only do I end up with a series of shorter columns, the numbers all change. How do I stop this from happening?

```
V1   V2   V3   V4
14   9     9    5
19   15   14    5
```

Comment: Whats' the output of `class(A)`?

Comment: Do you have `factor` class columns?

Comment: I changed the class of the columns to numeric so now at least the numbers aren't changing. But why can I still not combine the columns into one large column?

Comment: Maybe `c(A, B, C)` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
# example data frames
dt1 = data.frame(A = 1:5)
dt2 = data.frame(B = 3:10)
dt3 = data.frame(C = 5:7)

# change to a common column name
names(dt1) = "x"
names(dt2) = "x"
names(dt3) = "x"

# bind rows
rbind(dt1, dt2, dt3)

#     x
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   3
# 4   4
# 5   5
# 6   3
# 7   4
# 8   5
# 9   6
# 10  7
# 11  8
# 12  9
# 13 10
# 14  5
# 15  6
# 16  7
```